# How to programmatically generate WSDL for a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

Kindly let me know how to create WSDL for a WCF service programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MetadataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataset.aspx) and [WsdlImporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter.aspx) classes to do this if you have a mex endpoint exposed for whatever service it is that you are trying to generate WSDL against.

If the service you are trying to generate WSDL for is compiled code, you should be able to [make use of svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702581.aspx) for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate on creating a wsdl using wsdlimporter or a link to the document on the same.

Comment: If you take a look on the MSDN page for WsdlImporter, the sample they have should show you how to get the metadata from the endpoint. After that, the WsdlDocuments property on the importer should be what you are looking for (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter.wsdldocuments(v=VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
ContractDescription cd = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IContract));
System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter wexp = new System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter();
wexp.ExportContract(cd);
MetadataSet mds = wexp.GetGeneratedMetadata();
mds.WriteTo(new XmlTextWriter(@".\IContract.wsdl", Encoding.UTF8));
```

Also, here is good article about it:
http://mleder.blogspot.com/2008/05/creating-wsdl-using-c.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, other than programmatically using svcutil.exe to achieve the task.

Answer (score 0):

better late than never, but I think you're after the IWsdlExportExtension behaviour, which allows you to modify the WSDL generated by WCF when the service is hosted - [here](http://winterdom.com/2006/09/asampleiwsdlexportextensionforwcf) is a good blog post on how to get started when implementing this interface.